# Firebird copy from one database using isql

Tags: database, firebird, isql

I've got 2 firebird databases

```
c:\db1.gdb
c:\db2.gdb
```

both databases schema's are the same so both contain a table

```
MyTable
-------
Id int
Name varchar(50)
...etc
```

Its guaranteed that the data is different on both databases, however I need to copy from db2.MyTable into db1.MyTable

A requirement is that I do this using the firebird isql tool.

How would I firstly using isql

```
-Connect to both db's in one isql command window
-run a sql statement that would do a select all from one table in db2 and insert it into the same table in db1
```

I'm using firebird 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with FB 1.5. You can do this with Firebird 2.5 using the new "execute statement...external" feature that makes it possible to access another firebird database from inside triggers, procedures and code blocks.

Comment: After a bit of investigation I concur with your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you really must do it using `isql` then you could write `select` statement which produces `insert` statements; run the select in db2, save the result into some file and then execute the statements in db1. The select statement would be something like

```
select 'insert into MyTable(id, name) values ('|| cast(id as varchar(10)) ||','''|| name ||''');' from MyTable;
```

However the job is much easier to do using something like Clever Components' [Interbase DataPump](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/index.asp).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an alternative method of achieving the goal